# Can't open Android Studio - JVM issues

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm

I was working, when suddenly wanted to upgrade the performance of android studio and some forum suggested modifying VM Options. After doing that and restarting Android Studio, the error in the image below appears and until now I haven't been able to fix this problem. Please, I need your help!

[image: This error appears when Android Studio is launched]

Comment: You should tell us how did you modify the options. What they were before? What they are now?

Comment: I went to Help -> Edit Custom VM Options and then modify the Xmx, I searched in forums and they suggest me to edit the studio64.exe VMOPTIONS to go back to the early version but don't get anything

Comment: What were the complete options before (when, I assume, the Android studio was working) and what they are now?

Comment: When i go to my studio64.exe, i find this :      -Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=
-Didea.vendor.name=Google

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong there. Are you sure you changed only the "-Xmx" part?

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/android-studio/example/11146/customize-the-vm-option I use this link to modify my VM Options, after that I close and run again android studio but these windows appear "Error launching Studio".

Comment: There's a lot of bloat - I'd remove all those options and see if you can run the studio.